# How to get the Profile Pic & Post to Channel in Slack

Tags: javascript, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I am learning Slack, currently I am trying to fetch the profile pic of users and post that in a Slack general Channel.

I tried `users.profile.get` api and I am able to get some JSON Response but unclear in posting the image to Channel.

Response received:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "profile": {
        "title": "",
        "phone": "",
        "skype": "",
        "real_name": "azeez.gaa",
        "real_name_normalized": "azeez.gaa",
        "display_name": "",
        "display_name_normalized": "",
        "fields": null,
        "status_text": "",
        "status_emoji": "",
        "status_expiration": 0,
        "avatar_hash": "gd6ada77a40d",
        "email": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "image_24": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fslack.com%2Fdev-cdn%2Fv%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-24.png",
        "image_32": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-32.png",
        "image_48": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-48.png",
        "image_72": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=72&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-72.png",
        "image_192": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=192&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-192.png",
        "image_512": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=512&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-512.png",
        "status_text_canonical": ""
    }
}
```

I've seen `files.upload` api but not sure how to pass the content parameter.

Below is the code used to Send a message to Slack:

```
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++)
{
var rm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
rm.setHttpMethod('POST');
rm.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
rm.setEndpoint('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage');
var bodyString = '';
bodyString += 'token=' + encodeURIComponent('TOKEN');
bodyString += '&channel=' + encodeURIComponent('CKZLVKNFM');
bodyString += '&text=' + encodeURIComponent('HBD ' + arrayList[i]);
rm.setRequestBody(bodyString);
var response1 = rm.execute();
var responsebody = response1.getBody();
var statuscode = response1.getStatusCode();
response1.getAllHeaders();}
```

After running below code the get the response from SLACK:

```
var rm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
     rm.setLogLevel('all');
    rm.setHttpMethod('POST');
    rm.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    rm.setEndpoint('https://slack.com/api/users.info');
    //encodeURIComponent
    var bodyString = '';
    bodyString += 'token=' + encodeURIComponent('xoxb-691106198192-692978264951-MxWbFRMgjb8xo6B9I3yHEu3i');
    bodyString += '&user=' + encodeURIComponent('UL4NBK3BK');
    //bodyString += 
    //bodyString += '&text=' + encodeURIComponent('HBD ' + arrayList[i] + ', ');
    rm.setRequestBody(bodyString);
    var response1 = rm.execute();
    var responsebody = response1.getBody();
    var statuscode = response1.getStatusCode();
    response1.getAllHeaders();
gs.info("Response: " +responsebody);
//var js = JSON.parse(responsebody);
//var jsf = JSON.stringify(responsebody);

var jss = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(responsebody));
gs.info('Response Parsing: ' +jss);
gs.info('Response Parsing 11' +jss.user.profile.real_name);
```

Pasting the Response Received:

```
Response Parsing: 

{"ok":true,
"user":{
"id":"UL4NBK3BK","team_id":"TLB345U5N","name":"azeez.gaa","deleted":false,"color":"9f69e7","real_name":"azeez.gaa","tz":"Asia/Kolkata","tz_label":"India Standard Time","tz_offset":19800,
"profile":{"title":"","phone":"","skype":"","real_name":"azeez.gaa","real_name_normalized":"azeez.gaa","display_name":"","display_name_normalized":"","status_text":"","status_emoji":"","status_expiration":0,"avatar_hash":"gd6ada88a40d","email":"azeez.gaa@gmail.com",
"image_24":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fslack.com%2Fdev-cdn%2Fv%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-24.png",
"image_32":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-32.png",
"image_48":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-48.png",
"image_72":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=72&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-72.png",
"image_192":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=192&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-192.png",
"image_512":"https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=512&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-512.png","status_text_canonical":"","team":"TLB345U5N"},
"is_admin":true,"is_owner":true,"is_primary_owner":true,"is_restricted":false,"is_ultra_restricted":false,"is_bot":false,"is_app_user":false,"updated":1562821220}}
```

I am getting the response now, but please check the encoded URI i am able to send the message but cant post the image. i can manually the url and image is visible now.

```
var rm1 = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
    //rm.setLogLevel('all');
    rm1.setHttpMethod('POST');
    rm1.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    rm1.setEndpoint('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage');
    //encodeURIComponent
    var bodyString1 = '';
    bodyString1 += 'token=' + encodeURIComponent('xoxb-691106198192-692978264951-MxWbFRMgjb8xo6B9I3yHEu3i');
    bodyString1 += '&channel=' + encodeURIComponent('CKZLVKNFM');
bodyString1 += '&image_url=' +encodeURIComponent(grimage.user.profile.image_512);
    bodyString1 += '&text=' + encodeURIComponent('Congrats hhhh' );
    rm1.setRequestBody(bodyString1);

    var response11 = rm1.execute();
    var responsebody1 = response11.getBody();
    var statuscode1 = response11.getStatusCode();
    response11.getAllHeaders();
```

Logs

```
token=xoxb-692206198192-692978264951-MxWbFRMgjb8xo6B9I3yHEu3i&channel=CKZLVKNFM&image_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fd6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg%3Fs%3D512%26d%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fa.slack-edge.com%252F27b6e%252Fimg%252Favatars%252Fsmiley_blobs%252Fava_0016-512.png&text=Congrats%20hhhh
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your code. Now please also add a description what you want to achieve exactly and what your current issue is (e.g. errors)

Comment: i want to send a message along with the profile picture of the user. I am able to send the message but sending image is where i got stuck. I tried users.profile.get api to get the profile information and set pic the image url which i am unable to do. Can you please help me with the suggestion to make it work

Comment: If you are using node.js which it looks like I would recommend looking into the official Slack API lib from Slack. It makes developing for the Slack API way easier: https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk

Comment: No i am not using node.js, in the question you can see the response i received can you please help me how to figure it our which is image_url ???

Comment: kk. you can pick any URL that starts with `image_`. they are all the same image, just in different resolution. So `image_512` is 512x512 pixels.

Comment: Ok Let me try. 
var bodyString = '';
bodyString += 'token=' + encodeURIComponent('TOKEN');
bodyString += '&channel=' + encodeURIComponent('CKZLVKNFM');
bodyString += '&text=' + encodeURIComponent('HBD ' + arrayList[i]);
bodyString += '&image_url=' +encodeURIComponent('image_512": "https:\/\/secure.gravatar.com\/avatar\/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=512&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-512.png');
Is the syntax correct ?

Comment: I would suggest to convert the JSON you got from the API into an object first with [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp). Then you can use the URL better.

Comment: I am trying this in PostMan first where i am able to send a message but i dont see the image.
Body inputs i given is token, text, channel, image_url,. Output i can see a message but not image

Comment: You can add the JSON of the attachment to the question above? Then I can take a look. btw. If you use the JSON I posted in my answer below it works fine.

Comment: And if I may ask a favor please add all code to your question. its super hard to read in the comments

Comment: The code you posted in the comments has the URLs in the JSON form which will not work. You need to parse them into an JS object first. with JSON.parse()

Comment: Just updated the complete code and response receiving

Comment: ok cool. I think we are making progress. You are getting undefined, because that object does not exist. js.members is an array of member objects. Would suggest mapping them into an associate array with the `ìd` (= user ID) as key for easier use.

Comment: I just changed the End point to user.profile but still i am getting undefined :(

Answer (score 1):

`files.upload` would require you to first download the image to your local server and then you can upload it again to Slack.

It's a very powerful API method, but in your case it may be unnecessary since the profile image is already hosted on the Slack cloud.

Instead I would suggest to just include the image URL in the attachment of a normal message post. Since those URLs are public those will work fine.

Example message in JSON for sending with `chat.postMessage` etc.:

```js
{
    "channel": "test",
    "attachments":
    [
        {
            "text": "Profile pic",
            "image_url": "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/d6ada88a40de8504c6b6068db88266ad.jpg?s=512&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F27b6e%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fsmiley_blobs%2Fava_0016-512.png"
        }

    ]
}
```

In case you wonder about the extra backlashes in the URLs from your example. The string is JSON encoded and needs to be decoded first (which I did for the URL).

Here is an outline on how to send messages to users with their profile image to a channel:

1. Get the list of users you want to send messages to with their Slack user ID (if you don't have the Slack user ID call `users.list` and match based on email addresses).
2. Call `users.get.profile` for each user to get their image URLs
3. Send a message to each user. Add the image URL as attachments (see my example).

Make sure to respect the rate limits for the API calls, e.g. max. 1 message post per second.

I would maybe also add a mention to each user in the message, which you can do by adding `<@U1234567>` (with the correct user ID) to the text.

Comment: if you still want to use `files.upload` please see the many questions and examples on how it works here on SO. If you need more help please make sure to add your current code to the question.

Comment: Hi Erik, Agenda is to send a Birthday Message to the Slack users based on there birthday we need to send a message and photo. Currently we have Servicenow to Slack integration now we are pulling the DOB's from ServiceNow and posting a message in Slack using chat.postMessage api. Now the challenge is to send a picture of the user. Can you please help me in how to proceed with this ???

Comment: Below is how i am posting message using javascript:

//

Comment: Below is how i am posting message using javascript: for (i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) { var rm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2();
rm.setHttpMethod('POST');
rm.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
rm.setEndpoint('https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage');
//encodeURIComponent
var bodyString = '';
bodyString += 'token=' + encodeURIComponent('TOKEN');
bodyString += '&channel=' + encodeURIComponent('CKZLVKNFM');
bodyString += 
bodyString += '&text=' + encodeURIComponent('HBD ' + arrayList[i] + ', ');
rm.setRequestBody(bodyString);

Comment: var response1 = rm.execute();
var responsebody = response1.getBody();
var statuscode = response1.getStatusCode();
response1.getAllHeaders();}

Comment: Add the code to your question please. its really hard to read as comment ;-) If you are missing the reputation I can do it for you if you want (I can still see the deleted answer due to my higher level on SO)

Comment: I just added to the Question. Sorry for confusion